# How do regions of integration combine when performing a product of integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I'm a physicist attempting to symbolically evaluate a path integral. In order to do that, I need to know the following: I think that the double integral, $I:=\int_{E_1}d\mu\int_{E_2}d\mu f$ is writable as $I=\int_{g(E_1,E_2)}d^2\mu f$, however I'm not sure as to the form of $g$? So, my question is: how do the sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ generally combine into another set, $g(E_1,E_2)$ when they are being integrated over? (The specific integral I'm working with is integrated over a series of infinitely many shells, if that helps...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean $\int_{E_1}d\mu_1\int_{E_2}d\mu_2f=\int_{E_1\times E_2}d^2\mu f$, with $E_1\times E_2$ the Cartesian product. If $E_2$ is $\mu_1$-dependent, the integration range is more generally $\{(x,\,y)|x\in E_1,\,y\in E_2(x)\}$. Note the product of two contours is a surface.